# Android memory leak in activity which does nothing

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have an activity (Splashscreen) which does (for now) nothing except calling another activity.

Splashcreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

activity_splash_screen.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    >
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I dump the java heap I can see I have a memory leak inside SplashScreen.

[image]

If I comment setContentView method, I don't have any memory leak.
I don't really understand what happen and how can I solve it.

Thank you

Comment: try to remove android:background="#fff" and check again

Comment: Really guys.... If setting a background color causes a memory leak I should stop working on android apps! Can you recreate this consistently?

Comment: try clicking on `Inititate GC` and dump it again. It is probably just the GC being lazy

Comment: Yes everytime I launch my app I have that.
After clicking on Initiate GC and dump it again, it doesn't change anything.
Same after removing android:background.

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove this code. Hope works

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```